# Fn key locked - why/how to prevent?

Tags: laptop, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

While using my HP EliteBook 850 with Windows 10, sometimes it appears that the Fn key status is inverted (pressed/unpressed) until i visit `Keyboard Properties` via `All Tasks` and test the repetition rate.

For example, typing "Fn key locked" results in "Fn 2ey 36c2ed".

Why does this happen, and how can i stop that? [This page](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Software-and-How-To-Questions/How-do-I-lock-and-unclock-the-FN-key/td-p/45847) seems to recommend disabling the key in the BIOS, but i'd still like to control the volume and keyboard lights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a bit it seemed <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> enabled it and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> disabled it, but now it's consistently <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>num lk</kbd> that toggles it. Only that latter part makes sense; i guess my laptop's overheating.